# Preferred approaches to remote logging of a script / daemon?

Tags: remote, raspbian, syslog-ng

I run a script as a daemon which gets started and stopped via `/etc/init.d` on a Raspberry Pi.  For a number of reasons - including limited local file storage - I'd like to direct stdout and stderr from the script to a remote server for logging and post-mortem analysis.

At the risk of asking an overly general question: what's the preferred technique for remote logging?

Should I create a second process on the Raspberry Pi that does `tail -f` on whatever daemon creates?  Would `syslog-ng` be useful here?  Should I expect to write custom code on the remote server, or are there packages already set up to do this sort of stuff?

Etc.  I would be surprised if this wasn't already completely solved; I simply don't know what phrases and package names to Google.

Comment: Preliminary comment: It appears that a preferred approach is to call the system's generic syslog facility (e.g in Python, `syslog.syslog(message)`, and configure syslog to push its contents to a remote logger.  But that's only about 20% of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can write log files to a remote host in multiple ways.
As a comment points out, you could perhaps configure your syslog facility to do this for you.

Another way would be to simply mount a remote filesystem on the raspberry over nfs, ssh, samba, and write directly to it.

Here's how it can be done using nfs:

On the linux server: define your resource in /etc/exports:

```
/media/mydisk      10.10.30.0/24(rw,no_root_squash,subtree_check,insecure)
```

Install and start nfs

On the raspberry, in /etc/fstab:

```
server-name:/media/mydisk   /mnt/mydisk  nfs  auto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=10,timeo=14,soft,intr,noatime 0 0
```

Now you should be able to "mount /media/mydisk" on the rasberry and have it available upon boot.